# Mongodb - search without key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'd like to search documents in collection only by value. Let's say my collection contains documents like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57a443c74d854d192afcc451",
    "somekey": "123",
    "otherkey": "zxc"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57a443ca4d854d192afcc452",
    "key": "123",
    "otherkey": "123zxcvbnm"
  }
]
```

and now I want to get all documents where value of any key contains `123`.
I tried to do something like (written in `Ruby` and using `mongoid`):

```
new_search_query = { /.*/ => /#{v}/ }
collection.find(new_search_query)
```

but it looks like it is not suported becuase I get:

```
BSON::InvalidKey (Regexp instances are not allowed as keys in a BSON document.):
```

Is there any other manner or some workaround to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`full_text_search`](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search) of `mongoid` for rails app.

Comment: hmm probably it would work but in my case I don't use Models

Comment: then what is `collection.find(new_search_query)`?

Comment: it is a collection for instance of `Mongo::Client`

Comment: Oh, then you can try something like this `db.collection_name.find({ "collection_name.value" : "your search term" })`

Comment: Either I don't understand your concept or I doesn't make sens.
Do you mean the query like:
`db.my_test_collection.find({"my_test_collection": "zxc"})` ?

Comment: Yes, it's query for `mongo console` or for your `Mongo::Client` query executor

Comment: I would work like: find key with `my_test_collection` name with value `zxc`. It is not as I expect.

Comment: Do you know your keys that should have the 123 values? Or the keys are dynamic ?

Comment: And what is your expected output? You want the whole documents or only certain fields?

Comment: the key doesn't matter. I want to search by some string and search it via all values for any keys. Output are documents match to the query.